# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on request - Angular 4 / ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, angular, cors

I am trying to make an external api call but am running into a CORS issue. I am able to hit the api using Postman, but when trying from my Angular client I get

**'Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.'**

Here is how I make the call

```
        let params = new HttpParams()
            .set('id', itemId)

        let headers = new HttpHeaders()
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .set(this.apiKeyHeaderName, this.apiKey);

        let result = this.http.get<T>(this.url,
            { params: params, headers: headers }).share();

// do stuff with result
```

When inspecting the call in the Chrome Network tab > Preview, I see the error message

**The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'**

I know 'Content-Type', 'application/json' triggers the preflight request, I am tryng to understand the error messages better and see what needs to change in my code to make the request work.

This is the Request Headers

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type, api-key
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Connection: keep-alive
Host: xxxxxxxxxx
Origin: http://localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36
```

I see Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not being set which is why we get that error, but why? How can I configure setting this?

The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'
    What exactly is 'The requested resource' referring to? I'm assuming this is something on my side since I can hit the api with Postman.

I have done some research and added in my Web.config

```
<security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <verbs>
          <add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="true" />
        </verbs>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

and

```
<customHeaders>
…

        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />

…
</customHeaders>
```

And

```
 <handlers>
     <!-- <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" /> -->
</handlers>
```

But nothing works. Are these changes to Web.config actually doing anything in regards to how my app makes requests, or is this only relevant for if I were to have my own api and manage how requests to it are handled?

**--- Answered, I need to make the call from my backend, this way I won't run into CORS issues ---**

Comment: If you’re making a request to an external API endpoint that you don’t control, then there’s nothing you can do in your own client code to fix the problem described in the question. You’re never going to be able to make requests directly to that server from your frontend JavaScript code if the server responds to OPTIONS requests with a 405 or anything other than a 2xx success code. And it doesn’t matter what CORS config you do on your own server backend — the CORS config instead need to be changed on the third-party server that hosts the API endpoint to which you’re sending the request.

Comment: Your only alternative is to instead make the request from your backend/server-side code, and consume the response there. Because in that case, no OPTIONS request will be made to begin with, and more broadly, there’s no browser imposing cross-origin restrictions. (Because browsers are the enforcement point for cross-origin restrictions and for evaluating any CORS-protocol relaxation of those restrictions which the API-endpoint server might indicate it’s opting into.)

Comment: I agree with @sideshowbarker, I will have to do this from my backend code. I just needed to understand why exactly it should be this way, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you need to enable CORS on your ASP.NET API. The issue is not that the header is wrong but rather that the API is not expecting calls from your front end app's domain name. By default, major browsers will reject any HTTP call to URL that don't have have the same domain. To fix this issue you need to initialize CORS on your ASP.NET API and specify which origins are allowed to access your API's endpoints. I can see that you are trying to do so using your web.config, but it has to be enabled within your application. You can read more about this under Microsoft Documentation:

ASP.NET CORE 2.0:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.0

.NET FRAMEWORK 4.5:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: Ah, but I am not the one trying to create an API that can be called, I am trying to call an external api (not mine, not controlling it) from my application.

Comment: @Kelsey If API is third party and doesn't have CORS enabled, there is no easy way to hit the API with a browser. You will most likely have to create your own backend API and hit the Third party API with it and distribute it to your font end.

Comment: I think that is what I need to do as well, I just wanted to make sure I understood why, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you're running it on localhost. Try running it on the production server it may work there.

Answer (score 0):

For development, you can bypass the check by disabling web-security on chrome. The ideal solution would be enabling CORS in your `Web API`. To disable web-security on chrome you can do as follows.

**Kill all chrome instances before running command**

```
chromium-browser --disable-web-security
```